# Django REST framework: token authentication with HTML frontend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use token authentication with HTML frontend (like in this tutorial http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/ where they show how to render login form, but not how to actually login).

I have already a login function that returns token, but I don't know how to make web browser remember it and redirect somewhere else.

It is probably possible to pass the token to every template, but it seems a terrible practice

Answer (score 1):

I have taken the help of Sessions in the browsers. You can store your token in the session of the browser and whenever you need it just fetch it.

```
 $window.sessionStorage["token"] = response.data.token;
```

this is how I am storing it after my LOGIN API and store the token into session. To retrieve I use something like below:

```
headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Token ' + $window.sessionStorage['token']
          }
```

You can look into how to secure your sessions into the browser, also when logging out you can just destroy the session values.

Comment: alright, it worked! If I may ask one more thing, how do you use this header when redirecting to another URL via `window.location.href = response['redirect_url']`?